# Calling number with special characters in J2ME Nokia

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, nokia-s40, cldc

I want to call a number in the below format using platformRequest:

```
platformRequest("tel:number,number#number#");
```

But i'm getting an invalid number error , is it possible to do that?

Comment: What kind of number is that? I think, if you're looking to have a small pause, you can get one by inserting a "p". It's quite possible that a pause is represented by a comma in your phonebook though, but I think `platformRequest()` wants a "p" instead.

Comment: Something like this : 080099330,7495692664036#0096255455#

Comment: And what happens if you replace the comma with a "p"?

Comment: Thank you , it works now . But will it work on all Nokia mobiles which support Java?

Comment: You can never know for sure whether it'll work on any certain family of phones, when it comes to J2ME - unless you buy the real devices and test on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to put my comment as an answer here, so you can mark the question as answered.

You're getting an invalid number error because there's no comma in a telephone number.
When looking at your address book, there may be a comma as a visual representation of a pause in the number. But when using `platformRequest("tel:<number>);` you have to use the character "p" to get a pause.

So, a number like `080099330,7495692664036#0096255455#` in your phone-book will have to be entered like `platformRequest("tel:080099330p7495692664036#0096255455#");`
In other words, the comma is replaced with a p.